# Error: DPI-1047:Cannot locate a64-bit OracleClient library:"C:\APPS\OraClient\OraHome_12c\oci.dll is not the correct architecture"

Tags: node.js, oracle

I am new to Oracle. I'm not able to connect in Node with Oracle; getting some path issue:

> undefined-dbConnectionFactory: Error while cretaing the Idr DB Client, Error: Error: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "C:\APPS\OraClient\OraHome_12c\oci.dll is not the correct architecture

But my instant-client is at another location, I already set its path in the `PATH` variable: `D:\Users\instantclient\instantclient_19_5`. I already set the same path into plSQL. I am able to connect PLSQL but not with my code.

Comment: Did you read these instructions? https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html#instwin See the notes about PATH and how the directory must be before any other Oracle directories. There are also notes on using batch files to avoid interfering with existing tools that require other Oracle Client versions.

Comment: If your Node.js is 64 bit, then you need a 64-bit Oracle client library (oci.dll).  It looks like your PATH is picking up the client library included in your DB directories. 
 Restart the terminal (possibly the whole computer - it is Windows, after all) to make sure your new PATH is picked up.  Make sure you have the VS redistributable noted in the instruction manual.  If changing PATH affects other programs, you might need to create a BAT file that sets it to the Instant Client and then calls Node.js

Comment: sets D:\Users\instantclient\instantclient_19_5 into env file but at run time it picks C:\APPS\OraClient\OraHome_12c\oci.dll  not sure why this happens